# How to model UK addresses in Elasticsearch which can tolerate incorrect and partial queries?

Tags: elasticsearch, data-modeling, elastic-stack

I'm looking to provide a service that can take incorrect address match queries and provide best  address match. So far there's been some experimentation with full UK address blended into one single field and queries have been returning list of addresses out of which the top scoring address is picked as best match and it's been matching correctly about 40% - 60%. But are there better strategies for indexing UK addresses for being able to accommodate incorrect address match queries?

Also, when I say incorrect or partial that means I cannot guarantee the line 1, line 2 of addresses. So sometimes they may appear in the wrong order. There will be typos, along with abbreviations used for common terms like Rd. for Road. This could be sorted by using synonyms list. Another important thing is sometimes the post code is missing, this is quite rare though.

With that I'd like to be able to go to Elasticsearch, pick the right choice (or 1st match) automatically and have a good confidence that this match is indeed a correct one. I've millions of addresses like this so human intervention is not practical.

I was wondering if I didn't blend and indexed each field separately for each line of address in source data and apply some multi matching queries will that provide better accuracy. I was looking into the scoring mechanism and it looks like BM25 algorithm uses field length for example, and I don't know if that's of any significance when matching addresses in contrast to matching documents.

Answer (score -1):

Well it depends how you have indexed your data. If you matching single line addresses with multiple fields. e.q- 2, Alexandria Rd London W13 0NR with buildingName, unitName, street, city, postcode etc then you could say boost the score if postcode matches. you could also go one step further and say major post code has more boosting level in comparison with minor post code.

You could then say buildingName has more relevance followed by street, city etc. It all depends on how you have indexed the data.

But always remember one thing, matching addresses is something which can never be 100% correct. Some people will find it good while some people will find it crap.

When you have concept of historical, alternative or provisional addresses, you could then use multi match queries so that it picks up the best match.